# Global exception ignores and does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

When I run my api, and my ErrorController will ignore and does not work.
here is my program.cs class

```
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

my authController:

```
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AuthController:ControllerBase
{ 
   ...
   ...
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AccessToken")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AccessToken([FromBody] LoginCredential? credential)
    {
        var user = await 
        _userRepository.FindUserByEmail(credential.Email,credential.Password);
        if (user is null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = "Login Failed" });
        }
        var accessToken = GenerateToken(user);
        return Ok(new { AccessToken = accessToken });
    }
```

and finally ErrorsController class:

```
public class ErrorsController:ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/Error")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return Problem();
    }
}
```

however when I delete [Httpget] in ErrorsController I get "Ambiguous HTTP method for action" error.

Comment: What do you mean by “Does not work”? What behaviour are you getting?

Comment: And what gives you the “ambiguous action” error? Is it when you call another Api, when Swagger loads etc?

Comment: For instance when a user can not login, it ahould throw an error and error should call and send the problem as response, but this controller is being ignored.

Comment: But at no point in the code you're showing are you throwing an error. If the user is null, you return a bad request otherwise you return an Ok. The "error" controller will never be called

Comment: No matter if I change the bad request to new exception it will not work.

Comment: Then please put a minimal example on GitHub with the issue because I can’t reproduce it with the code you’ve provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been explained in this document:

**Don't mark the error handler action method with HTTP method attributes, such as HttpGet. Explicit verbs prevent some requests from reaching the action method.
For web APIs that use Swagger / OpenAPI, mark the error handler action with the [ApiExplorerSettings] attribute and set its IgnoreApi property to true.**

If you add [HttpGet] Attribute on your Error method, when you get error in a post method,It won't get into the method and throw 405 Error,and if you delete the [HttpGet] Attribute without adding [ApiExplorerSettings] ,swagger would throw `Ambiguous HTTP method for action`

I tried as below in my case:

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{    app.UseSwagger();    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
//make sure there're on other error handle middlewares behind it
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The controller:

```
[ApiController]
    public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("/error")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        
        public IActionResult HandleError()
        {
            return Problem();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

When it comes to handling  validation  failure error response,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler-1) for more details